# Function is still executing after if Statment

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, if-statement

I am running an IF statement that checks if a JSON response is empty, to execute the next function, however, its executing both.  Below is a sample of the JSON response that has 3 objects in the "count_business" an example of my function is below.   I am running a .length < 1 but it seems to not check that.

JSON

```
{
    "count_business": 3,
    "business": [
        {
            "id": "Business.3b725ab1-1eeb-4f11-bb41-0a97cdd5475a",
            "name": "Dogwood Valley Press LLC",
            "industry": [
                "Sporting Goods, Hobby, Musical Instrument, and Book Stores"
            ],
            "found_at_address": {
                "id": "Location.86fc8e6b-6dfb-446d-9488-aae59fea6eb2",
                "location_type": "Address",
                "street_line_1": "1604 Lincoln Ln",
                "street_line_2": null,
                "city": "Rolla",
                "postal_code": "65401",
                "zip4": "2614",
                "state_code": "MO",
                "country_code": "US",
                "lat_long": {
                    "latitude": 37.956933,
                    "longitude": -91.743859,
                    "accuracy": "RoofTop"
                },
                "is_active": true,
                "delivery_point": "SingleUnit",
                "link_to_business_start_date": "2016-06-12",
                "link_to_business_end_date": null
            },
```

My if statement

```
if(res.data.count_business < 1){
                    fetchGooglePlace(data)

                  }else{
                    console.log(chalk.white('RUNNING WHITEPAGES'));
                      for(let i =0; i < res.data.business.length; i++ ){

                          console.log(res.data.business[i].name);
                          console.log(res.data.business[i].found_at_address.street_line_1);

                          /*Second loop to fetch phone numbers from array in whitePages JSON */
                          for (let x = 0; x < res.data.business[i].phones.length; x++) {
                              console.log(res.data.business[i].phones[x].phone_number);
                              console.log('          ');

                          }
                      }
                  }
                })
```

After executing the app, it runs the whitePages API and also the fetchGooglePlace function.

Comment: If the `else` body is running, `res.data.count_business < 1` must be false at some point. You'll need to debug that. In your example though, it's false.

Comment: You might try `parseInt(res.data.count_business)` if you are going to evaluate the value as an integer.

Comment: the `if` Statement evaluates to false that is why the `else` statement is executing

Comment: @RandyCasburn parseInt() worked.

Comment: of course - glad to help. This simple idea is lost on lots of people who are new to the language.